# IOS Map (Google Map API vs. MapKit?)

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, mapkit

I'm trying to make an iOS app that shows my location on a map and shows some stores (as pins) around me. I want the store pins to be clickable so that below the map there will be a label showing the details for this store when user clicked/touched the pin. My question is should I use MapKit or Google Maps API?

If Mapkit, I'm building in XCode 4.2, the only framework i see is iOS 5 -> MapKit Framework, if i use it, would my app still work on phones with iOS 4?

If Google Maps API, I believe I'll have to use a web-view then load a html googlemaps page. How would I detect a click event on the store pin and send this message to my label below the webview?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MapKit.framework is the most right choice for an App.
You can set the Deployment Target to 4.0 in Xcode, then the App will run on iOS 4 correctly.
(But you can't use Storyboard for interface builder.)

Web App is significantly slower than native App right now.

Hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that you use a webView if you are using Google's API. You can make use of MKMapView to show stores around you. And in mapView, giving annotations to stores is quite a simple thing. Google Places API is the right place you have to reach. They provide you a request response either in Json or in XML(as you wish). All you have to do is parse it out and drop pin-annotations.

Comment: is Google API not deprecated?

Comment: thanks for ur respons,any idea how to get lat and long values from zipcode using Google API?

Comment: I actually dont believe thats possible, because zip codes are country specific. But if you have a lat and long you can get an address of-course. In case you asked the question wrongly I can help you.

Comment: you got my question correct.. for google place api location type should be lat and long value (zip code and address doesnt work)